# Error occures when deploying theme to liferay portal. "No theme found for specified theme id ."

Tags: java, deployment, themes, liferay-6

I've create sample theme, i.e. custom.css according to liferay tutorial, and don't know why my theme is not deployed, in the log file is the next content:
"No theme found for specified theme id . Returning the default theme."
And in the themes in "Manage->Page->Look and Feel" there is no my theme

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This warning messages will be displayed when you have already applied a theme to the site(Community) but That theme is now undeployed currently. This can happen due to the recent changes that you have made to the theme. please try reverting the changes that you have made, and make sure that your theme get registered successfully when you deployed.

if the problem still persists, please let us know error log statements or What are the exact changes that you have done to the theme.

---

I Think your theme is getting deployed to glassfish, but not getting registered to Liferay.

May be there is a problem in your deployment process, can you please set these properties accordingly in your portal-ext.properties file

```
'
#
# Set this to true to enable auto deploy of layout templates, portlets, and
# themes.
#
auto.deploy.enabled=true

#
# Set the directory to scan for layout templates, portlets, and themes to
# auto deploy.
#
auto.deploy.deploy.dir=${liferay.home}/deploy

#
# Set the directory where auto deployed WARs are copied to. The application
# server or servlet container must know to listen on that directory.
# Different containers have different hot deploy paths. For example, Tomcat
# listens on "${catalina.base}/webapps" whereas JBoss listens on
# "${jboss.server.home.dir}/deploy". Set a blank directory to automatically
# use the application server specific directory.
#
auto.deploy.dest.dir=
auto.deploy.default.dest.dir=../webapps
auto.deploy.geronimo.dest.dir=${org.apache.geronimo.home.dir}/deploy
auto.deploy.glassfish.dest.dir=${com.sun.aas.instanceRoot}/autodeploy
auto.deploy.jboss.dest.dir=${jboss.server.home.dir}/deploy
auto.deploy.jetty.dest.dir=${jetty.home}/webapps
auto.deploy.jonas.dest.dir=${jonas.base}/deploy
auto.deploy.resin.dest.dir=${resin.home}/webapps
auto.deploy.tomcat.dest.dir=${catalina.base}/webapps
auto.deploy.weblogic.dest.dir=${env.DOMAIN_HOME}/autodeploy
```

'

After configuring this specific to glassfish, you should see log message saying

1 Themes for mytheme registered successfully.

Comment: I just change the style in the _diffs/custom.css to check changes and it contains "body{display:none;}", and it don't change.

Comment: Your changes might not be the reason for the problem you are facing. 

few things that you need to check:
1. custom.css should be in _diffs/css/custom.css, but you are saying _diffs/custom.css. Can you please recheck?
2. custom.css has been added in main.css
3. Please restart the server and delete browser chache. This is to ensure you have cleared the cache.

Comment: I'm sorry, I wrote wrong, actually it in the _diffs/css/custom.css

Comment: Here is the log file for "ant deploy" http://textsave.de/?p=130814 and http://textsave.de/?p=130817

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with DEV/QA environment, please update portal-ext.properties file:

**include-and-override=portal-developer.properties**

If that is on Staging/Production just try to delete **/css** folder from **YourThemeName/** directory on server  before deploying updated version.