# How to import existing theme directory into different Liferay server instance?

Tags: plugins, liferay, liferay-6, liferay-theme, liferay-ide

I am trying to import a theme (LP5-ellucian-theme) from my organizations test server to a local instance of Liferay so that I can do some custom theme development, which I will later upload back to the test server.

My question: What is the best way for me to import my LP5-ellucian-theme directory into my local instance of Liferay?

I tried creating a new Liferay theme project in Eclipse, copying all the files (except _diffs) from LP5-ellucian-theme/docroot into my new theme's _diffs folder, and then deploying to the server. However, when I switch my portals display setting to use this lp5 theme, the theme stays the same and I get the following message:

```
16:12:13,798 WARN  [http-bio-8080-exec-6][ThemeLocalServiceImpl:151] No theme found for specified theme id lp5_WAR_lp5theme. Returning the default theme.
16:12:14,489 WARN  [http-bio-8080-exec-6][ThemeLocalServiceImpl:151] No theme found for specified theme id lp5_WAR_lp5theme. Returning the default theme.
16:12:14,491 WARN  [http-bio-8080-exec-11][ThemeLocalServiceImpl:151] No theme found for specified theme id lp5_WAR_lp5theme. Returning the default theme.
16:12:14,492 WARN  [http-bio-8080-exec-12][ThemeLocalServiceImpl:151] No theme found for specified theme id lp5_WAR_lp5theme. Returning the default theme.
16:12:14,492 WARN  [http-bio-8080-exec-10][ThemeLocalServiceImpl:151] No theme found for specified theme id lp5_WAR_lp5theme. Returning the default theme.
16:12:14,492 WARN  [http-bio-8080-exec-1][ThemeLocalServiceImpl:151] No theme found for specified theme id lp5_WAR_lp5theme. Returning the default theme.
16:12:15,895 WARN  [http-bio-8080-exec-1][ThemeLocalServiceImpl:151] No theme found for specified theme id lp5_WAR_lp5theme. Returning the default theme.
16:12:16,312 WARN  [http-bio-8080-exec-4][ThemeLocalServiceImpl:151] No theme found for specified theme id lp5_WAR_lp5theme. Returning the default theme.
16:12:18,638 WARN  [http-bio-8080-exec-12][ThemeLocalServiceImpl:151] No theme found for specified theme id lp5_WAR_lp5theme. Returning the default theme.
```

Is there a better way I could be doing this?

Here are my local dev env details:

- Plugins SDK 6.2
- Liferay Portal-Tomcat 6.2
- JRE 7.0
- Eclipse Kepler

The test server which I pulled the theme from is running on Liferay Portal 6.1

Answer (score 1):

Remember that theme development is quite different from liferay 6.1 to liferay 6.2.
You cannot look to have a successful result without rewrite some parts of the theme.

Start from scratch and write a new theme. It's the best way.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you create a new theme using the create command in your 6.2 environment and then add the code in your generated files. You shouldnt just copy the complete files. The error looks like your theme is not registered. Did you verify that your theme deployed correctly and the name with which it is deployed?

Answer (score 0):

Possible solutions.

[Error occures when deploying theme to liferay portal. "No theme found for specified theme id ."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11721220/error-occures-when-deploying-theme-to-liferay-portal-no-theme-found-for-specif)

https://www.themeray.com/blog/-/blogs/no-theme-found-for-specified-theme-id-%E2%80%A6-returning-the-default-theme

Hope this helps.